# How to use ember-power-select in {{#each}} block

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, ember-addon

I am generating ember-power-select box using {{#each}} block in hbs template as shown in the code below.

```
{{#each hps as |hp|}}

{{#power-select
  search=(action "searchRepo")
  selected=selected
  onchange=(action (mut selected))
  as |repo|
}}
  {{repo.name}}
{{/power-select}}

{{/each}}
```

The above code generates two select boxes. But when I select a value in the first box,the same value gets replicated in the second box too.

What is the way to differentiate the two select boxes?

Answer (score 3):

This works for me

```
// Controller
roles: ['Project Manager', 'Tech Lead', 'Member'],

<ul>
{{#each user.projectRoles as |projectRole|}}
    <li>
        <label>{{projectRole.project}}</label>
        {{#power-select selected=projectRole.role options=roles onchange=(action (mut projectRole.role)) as |role|}}
        {{role}}
        {{/power-select}}
    </li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of that *may* work is declaring `selected` as an array and bind every power select `selected` property to the correspondent index of the `hp` array.

For example, assuming you're using a component:

```js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    selected: Ember.A()
});
```

Then, in your component template:

```
{{#each hps as |hp hp_index|}}

    {{#power-select
      search=(action "searchRepo")
      selected=selected.[hp_index]
      onchange=(action (mut selected))
      as |repo|
    }}
      {{repo.name}}
    {{/power-select}}

{{/each}}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. The value is not getting selected from the drop down.

Comment: how to set index for this type? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37656662/ember-power-select-changing-the-value-in-one-power-select-box-it-alternately @terseus

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly happening of because you are assigning same `as |repo|` in both of the select statements so whenever you change one it is reflecting in the both.
`{{#power-select}}`do not have option like this better you try with some other one
**or**
 else you define two `{{#power-select}}` with different `as |repo2|`